# Draw circles using D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, dreamweaver, html

The following code is supoosed to draw five circles next to each other

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.3.0.js'></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="viz"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset = [],
    i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
    }        

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 400)
        .attr("height", 400);    

    sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .attr("height", 40)
        .attr("width", 75)
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 20);

  </script>
 </html>
```

It is not really my code I just copied it from this website
http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/

The problem is that this code does not draw any circle.
Although that when I try to use the chrome's tool inspect element, I find that the circles are there but they are not visible.

I thought that the reason is the white colour of the circles although the stroke is not.
However changing the colour was not really useful.

And the problem is that Dreamweaver is not really helping as it does for HTML or JavaScript for example.

Any suggestions for the solution of this issue, or any recommendation for the editor ?

Comment: You're never closing `<body>`. Is that intentional?

Comment: No, it is not. 
However it does really make a difference, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: Hmm, `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attributes also mean nothing to SVG circles. They're [defined by](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/shapes.html#CircleElement) `cx`, `cy` and `r`. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/PdMWA/1/). (The reason that's showing one circle is because all five are stacked in the same position.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you took an example that generated rectangles and changed it to circles but circles don't have x, y, height and width attributes, they have [cx, cy and radius attributes instead](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement).

```
sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 20);
```

Will draw multiple circles one on top of another.

Answer (score 5):

@Robert Longson
Thank Robert Longson

And if you want to avoid the interlapping between the circles
Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataset = [],
    i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        dataset.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
    }

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 300);    

    sampleSVG.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 40)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i){return 50 + (i*80)})
    .attr("cy", 120);
</script>
```